# Reset radio-button state in Angular 9

Tags: angular, radio-button, material-design, reset, radio-group

I am using Angular 9 and mat-radio-button. I fill in the user passport with data from the server. I wanted to immediately select the right radio-button when receiving data, so I set up two-way binding. The radio-button is selectable. But if I open another user passport, then in the new passport radio-button is selected, and in the old passport it completely disappears - not a single radio-button is selected. All other user data remains on the form. Moreover, in the model all the information is saved, and when you select a radio-button, the information changes. Tell me, please, what could be the problem?

**user.component.html**

```html
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Пол" [(ngModel)]="user.gender.id" name="gender">
    <mat-radio-button [value]=1>Муж.</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button [value]=2>Жен.</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

**user.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../service/user.service';
import { User } from '../../models/user/user';
import { Data } from '../../../home/home.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  public user: User;

  constructor(data: Data, private userService: UserService) {
    if (data != undefined) {
      this.user = data as unknown as User;
      this.Get(this.user.id);
    }
    else {
      this.user = new User();
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  private Get(id: number) {
    this.userService.Get(id).subscribe(
      data => { this.user = (data as any).user as User; }
    );
  }
}
```

**user.ts**

```ts
import { Gender } from "../doctors/Gender";
export class User {
  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public surname: string;
  public patronymic: string;
  public gender: Gender;
  public login: string;
  public passwordHash: string;
  public birthday: Date;
  public employmentDateInAlpha: Date;
  constructor() {
    this.id = 0;
    this.name = '';
    this.surname = '';
    this.patronymic = '';
    this.gender = new Gender();
    this.login = '';
    this.passwordHash = '';
    this.birthday = new Date();
    this.employmentDateInAlpha = new Date();
  }
}
```

**gender.ts**

```ts
export class Gender {
  public id: number;
  public name: string;

  constructor() {
    this.id = 3;
    this.name = 'Не задан';
  }
}
```

[This is what the user passport object looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzo5i.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the question myself. My `<mat-radio-group>` was inside

```
<mat-card>
   <form class = "example-form">
      ...
   </form>
</mat-card>
```

I replaced `<form>` with `<mat-card-content>` and removed `name = "gender"` from `<mat-radio-group>`, and only after that did the binding work and the radio-button state stopped reset. I did not think that this could be a problem.